# Linear functional preserving monotone limits

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology

Let $V$ be a vector space of functions on a set $X$. Let $\phi$ be a linear functional that preserves pointwise *monotone* limits, i.e., if $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions such that for some $f\in V$:

- For every $x\in X$, $f_n(x)\ge f_{n+1}(x)$;
- For every $x\in X$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$

we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi(f_n)=f$.

How do we call such a functional? Are these functionals studied? What are their properties?

Comment: bounded linear operators are continuous, thus they respect limit operations.

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, but are all functionals in this form continuous in general?